# I'm encountering a dynamic import issue when utilizing the React hook useEffect inside a remote component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, import, vite, esbuild

I'm not sure if this is an esbuild issue, but when using it to build a remote React component that is dynamically imported inside the main app, I encounter an error when the remote component uses the React hook useEffect. Everything works fine when useEffect is commented out

Here is a simplified Git repository prepared for testing https://github.com/msantic/react-useeffect-dynamic-import

I would appreciate any help since I got stuck on this one. Thank you

I have two separate projects. One of them is a main app that can dynamically import React components from a separate remote component server. I encounter an error when the remote component uses the React hook useEffect